# Hibernate: Cannot create entity manager factory after connection reset

Tags: java, database, hibernate

We are using hibernate in a RESTful web service to query a sql server database on another server.

If there is a socket exception such as connection reset during the query execution then further attempts, in subsequent web service requests, to create an entity manager factory via Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory() result in:

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2119)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2115)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:126)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:52)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:34)
    at au.com.intunity.raceresults.service.impl.CompetitorInformationBean.getRaceResult(CompetitorInformationBean.java:79)

Any ideas how I can solve this problem?  Thanks.

Comment: Do you use anything for connection pooling that might be left in an unstable state?

Comment: Which version of Hibernate are you using? That would tell us what is causing the NullPointerException. If you are using Hibernate 3.3.2, for example, line 151 is `properties.putAll(dialect.getDefaultProperties());` which suggests that Hibernate doesn't know what dialect to use and so  `dialect` is `null`.